# How to make a contact's phone number clickable to call and to send a message in ionic?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I cloned the ionic project from [GitHub](https://github.com/calendee/ionicPickContact)

While the contact's phone number is not clickable to call and message. So for the index.html file line 39, I converted from

```
<p ng-if="contact.emails.length > 0">{{contact.emails[0].type}} : {{contact.emails[0].value}}</p>
```

to

```
<p ng-if="contact.phones.length > 0">{{contact.phones[0].type}} : <a ng-href='{{contact.phones[0].value}}'>{{contact.phones[0].value}}</a></p>
```

But it turns out the app will not load any contact's information anymore.

Is there anything I missed or am I totally wrong on sending data?

Comment: We need to see the value of the variable you are passing to ng-href. All that the anchor tag needs to have passed is href="tel:numberwithnospacesordashes".

Comment: In fact could you throw the controller code that populates those values up as well? It will help with diagnosis.

Comment: Did you install plugin ?  cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.contacts ?

Answer (score 8):

to make phone call with ionic you need to add this code in confi.xml

```
<access launch-external="yes" origin="tel:*" />
```

and in your view you need to add:

```
<a ng-href=tel:{{user.phoneNumber}} class="button button-positive">Call me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

I've just noticed it's (probably) an issue with loading data not the link itself. Would need to see your controller code to know more about why it's not populating the ng-href if it's not the issue below...

**Previously:**

Using the following href should be enough to trigger a call:

`tel:' + number`

Angular (which ionic sits on) doesn't like anything unusual going into an anchors href unless you tell it you want it to. See here:

http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ng-href-tel-redirecting-to-call-with-empty-number/4567/2

The quickest fix, if you 'just' want it to work is this in your view:

```
<p ng-if="contact.phones.length > 0">{{contact.phones[0].type}} : <a href="#" ng-click="triggerCall('{{contact.phones[0].value}}')">{{contact.phones[0].value}}</a></p>
```

and then in your controller:

```
$scope.triggerCall = function(number){
    document.location.href = 'tel:' + number
}
```