# IONIC/cordova, make phone calls background

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm developing an app with Ionic and AngluarJs and I'm searching for a way to make a background phone call when I trigger an event, do anyone know a way to do it?

I used till now this:

```js
window.open('tel:555-555-555', '_blank', 'location=no,hidden=yes');
```

Here i used $cordovaInAppBrowser plugin but it doesn't run in background.

Comment: Try https://github.com/Rohfosho/CordovaCallNumberPlugin

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37183398/6279687

below

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

add this in **config.xml**

```
<access launch-external="yes" origin="tel:*" />
```

and in your view you need to add:

```
<a ng-href=tel:{{user.phoneNumber}} class="button button-positive">Call me</a>
```